# Validation of title on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug

For question title of 150 spaces + 16 characters `"                                                                                                                                                      15 charctersxxxx"` it says *Title cannot be longer than 150 characters.*
So, it is not trimmed before this validation.

For question title of 15 spaces + 3 characters `"               xxx"` it says *Title must be at least 15 characters.* So, it is trimmed before this validation.

Why to trim before one validation and not trim before another?

Comment: Probably because people habitually try to use padding to make a title longer, but rarely do they try to make the title too long. The trimming for the minimum length check is there to defeat people trying to cheat the system, but that's not needed on the 'too long' end.

Comment: But in the end, stackoverflow will trim te title, for example 100 spaces + 20 characters, after posting it will show only that 20 characters, why not to trim before every validation ?

Comment: At some point, users need to be accountable for their actions.  I don't see the value of fixing this.

Comment: so, 20 spaces + 20 characters is ok, after are shown only 20 characters(btw if is ok, why do you trim user input?), but 20 spaces + 10 characters is not ok?

Comment: Shouldn't all of the trimming/data manipulation happen before it goes to do any validation?

Comment: It is intentional, validation on titles with a lot of spaces killed SO before.  Something to do with a recursive regex expression that caused the web servers to burn 100% core, I can't find the meta post about it back.

Comment: why to use regexp for validation title length?

Comment: @Romper they use regex for other things related to "validating the title", not just length.

Comment: why not to validate length and after to validate other things?

Comment: @HansPassant http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016

Comment: The real answer here is more likely "an oversight ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯". :) @Romper, if you want, feel free to retag this as a bug. Low priority, but doesn't hurt to report it.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, we look at bug reports. What gets fixed is generally determined by how much time we have and severity of the issues. At the moment there are [1962 open questions tagged bug *and* one of the status tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bstatus*%5D+closed%3A0).